# How to trim the output from an Object - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress with GDrating plugin, below code(as it is) will display the rating on my Wordpress page.

```
 if (gdrtsm_stars_rating()->loop()->has_votes()) {
                gdrtsm_stars_rating()->loop()->render()->text();
 }
```

This code return the output like

> Rating: 9.3. From 1 vote.

I want to trim the From 1 vote part from the output, so I tried with rtrim and substring but it not worked well. Is there any way to trim the last characters without disturbing the core functions?

Desired output:

> Rating: 9.3.

Sorry, I couldn't post all the functions.

Comment: What have you tried? If you just want everything before " From", you can use `strstr($originalStr, ' From', true)`

Comment: I guess you need to manipulate the value before render.

Comment: Could use `explode('. ', trim($str))[0]` or regex.. what have you tried?

Comment: I tried rtrim, but it is not trimming.

Comment: @Phil as I mentioned in the post, I have tried that but it is not trimming.

Comment: What's not mentioned in the post - and what's frustrating - is that you aren't showing _how you are attempting to modify the output_, or where the output is being generated.  Solving the problem is _simple_ - once you've identified where / how the output is being rendered.  (BTW, it's super simple: `$output = explode('From', $output); echo $output[0];`)

Comment: @cale_b I know its quite simple but none of traditional ways worked. So, I have posted here. If you know the Wordpress GD Rating functions then you wouldn't frustrate. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If it's always outputting the "From" part (sorry I'm not too familiar with GDrating) you could always use :

$rating = substr($gdr_output, 0, strpos($gdr_ouput, "From"));

This way you'll get everything from $gdr_output ("Rating: 9.3. From 1 vote.") up to the "From" string.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the solution really manipulated the output. So, I mirrored base function with different name and modified the string in the function itself and called the modified function.

```
    if (is_null($atts['tpl_rating'])) {
        $atts['tpl_rating'] = __("Rating", "gd-rating-system").'<strong>%1$s</strong>';

        if ($atts['show_max']) {
            $atts['tpl_rating'].= '/%2$s';
        }

      //  $atts['tpl_rating'].= '.';
    }
```

Commented this and some other functions in render.php

```
  /*
    if ($atts['show_votes']) {
        $_votes = $this->owner()->value('votes', false);

        if (is_null($atts['tpl_votes'])) {
            $render.= ' '.sprintf(_n("From %s vote.", "From %s votes.", $_votes, "gd-rating-system"), $_votes);
        } else {
            $render.= ' '.sprintf(_n($atts['tpl_votes']['singular'], $atts['tpl_votes']['plural'], $_votes, "gd-rating-system"), $_votes);
        }
    }
    */
```